# Exibir div de notificação com áudio JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html

Então, fiz um codigo com jquery que após 8 segundos de página index aberta exibe uma div de mensagem com áudio.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Mostra a div após 8 segundos
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.informativo').show().append('<embed src="<?php echo $address ?>sound.mp3" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="false">');
        // Esconde a div após 8 segundos
        setInterval(function () {
                $('.informativo').fadeOut();
        }, 8000);
    }, 4000);        
});    

<div class="informativo">
    <p>Mensagem de alerta com audio</p>
</div>
```

Mas estou tendo um problema que se eu abro essa página index e mudo de aba, a div aparece na aba index normal, mas o audio só roda quando eu volto na index!

Queria que o áudio no embed rodasse mesmo, eu estando em outra aba!

Comment: Pode postar o código completo com o relativo HTML para podermos testar?

Comment: Na verdade se o áudio já estiver sendo executado e trocar de aba ele continuará sendo executado.

Comment: Postei o HTML necessário

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo então na verdade o som é bem rápido! após 8 segundos que ele aparece com a div e se eu abrir a pagina e mudar de aba antes dos 8 segundos, ele não toca ! Só toca quando eu retorno pra aba do sistema

Comment: Isso, mas se ele estiver já sendo executado, vai continuar sendo executado independente de qual página vc estiver navegando desde q vc não feche a aba do audio

Comment: Cara realmente seu código ai não dá erro! Aqui  o meu não funciona de jeito maneira

Comment: Pega no código fonte da página

Comment: Não dá para entender, eu só coloquei o URL do áudio no seu código

Comment: Estranho demais cara, vou tentar limpar meu cache! Pra ver se adianta algo!

Comment: qual navegador?

Comment: Chrome e atualizado!

Comment: Em vez de usar `setTimeout()`, Experimente trocar o atraso por delay: `$('.informativo').show().apped('...').delay(8000);`, dessa forma vc vai disparar a espera do evento logo no início, esse `setInterval()` vai ficar se repetindo eternamente enquanto a aba estiver aberta a cada 8 segundos, era para ser isso mesmo? O áudio só vai parar se vc fechar a aba.

Answer (score -1):

O código está sendo usado em PHP, seria a index.php, configure um arquivo em JS que tenha PHP e chama ele no header da index;

```
 <embed src="<?php echo $address ?>sound.mp3" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="false">
```

Quando você sai da `index.php` a outra página não consegue localizar o diretório da música porque você talvez tenha coloca o código apenas em uma página.